# test statistic for change in proportion over time?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, proportion

Stats novice here. This is my problem:

I have 7 samples corresponding to the years 2006-2012, representing emergency department [ED] visits. For each ED visit, X=1 if the visit had diagnostic criteria for a hypertensive emergency, and X=0 otherwise.

In 2006, X=1 for about 1/2,000 ED visits.
By 2012, X=1 for about 1/1,000 ED visits.

This proportion of ED visits for which X=1 rose monotonically in the period from 2006 to 2012 in my samples.

I'd like to test the null hypothesis that the proportion of ED visits for which X=1 did not change in the period from 2006-2012.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!